# ARM-based arduino-type system much slower than AVR-based for same math

Tags: c, arm, arduino

I'm working on some robotics kinematics code, and I first wrote the naive, intentionally non-optimized function for calculating joint angles, so that I could measure the timings with a logic analyzer and have a tangible way of measuring the gains in optimizations such as fixed-point math.

I have two microcontroller boards that I'm playing with: a Teensy 2.0 and a Teensy 3.0.  I'm using the Arduino environment to build code for them.  The 2.0 is an 8-bit 16MHz AVR, like most Arduinos.  The 3.0 is a 32-bit 48MHz ARM cortex M4.

The code pulls a pin low, does one leg's IK calculations, and then pulls the pin back high.  I'm using an ancient logic analyzer to measure the time that the line is low.

The bizarre thing is that the ARM board has SIGNIFICANTLY longer time between edges!  The AVR does it in around 960us, but the ARM takes more like 18.5ms!

This doesn't add up in my mind.  Does anyone have any insight into why this could be?

[image: logic analyzer timing of AVR board, 960.0us]

[image: logic analyzer timing of ARM board, 18.5ms]

Here's the code I'm using.  Don't mind the fact that it's intentionally non-optimized, and probably I'm bad at math, but that's not the question here :)

```
#include <math.h>

#define lc 21.0
#define lf 40.0
#define lt 62.0

#define lfsqrd 1600.0
#define ltsqrd 3844.0

struct Vector {
  double x;
  double y;
  double z;
};

struct Joints {
  double c;
  double f;
  double t;
};

void calc_joints(struct Vector *foot, struct Joints *joints) {
   double l1 = sqrt(pow(foot->y,2) + pow(foot->x, 2));
   double l2 = l1 - lc;
   double l3 = sqrt(pow(foot->z,2) + pow(l2, 2));

   double tx = atan2(l2, foot->z);
   double ty = acos( (pow(l3,2) + lfsqrd - ltsqrd) / (2 * l3 * lf) );

  // todo: convert these from radians to degrees
   joints->c = atan2(foot->y, foot->x);
   joints->f = tx + ty;
   joints->t = acos( (lfsqrd + ltsqrd - pow(l3,2)) / (2 * lf * lt) );
}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(0, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(0, HIGH);
}

void loop() {
    digitalWrite(0, LOW);
    struct Vector v = { 10, 20, 30 };
    struct Joints j;

    calc_joints(&v, &j);
    digitalWrite(0, HIGH);


    Serial.print(j.c);    
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.print(j.f);    
    Serial.print(", ");
    Serial.println(j.t); 
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at what the pin response time lag is for both parts?

Comment: No, and I'm not sure what the best way to go about measuring lag specifically would be.  Also, if it were lag, wouldn't it lag equally on both the high and the low writes, and cancel out?  Maybe not, maybe I'm not thinking about it correctly.

Comment: As a test, just do `void loop(){digitalWrite(0, LOW); digitalWrite(0, HIGH);` and see what the scope says. However, you have a good point. I'm probably wrong about there being lag. Are you hooked directly to the microcontroller pins of each?

Comment: did that on the AVR, and I get somewhere in the vicinity of 110ns low, 700ns high.  Pretty darn insignificant on the order of what I'm seeing elsewhere. I'm about to try it on the ARM.

Comment: The ARM is slower even here... I get 700ns low, 1000ns high.  I'm starting to wonder if maybe there are ISRs or something running in the background that I'm not aware of.

Comment: What optimization level do you have for each?  Have you looked at the assembly?  Are you using the same vendor for each?  The math.h implementation may be different for the two processors.  Not "minding the fact that it is non-optimized" is probably a red herring to begin with and not worth the time to investigate?  How about trying to look at your best attempt at production code?

Comment: I'm using the Arduino IDE for it, and unfortunately I don't understand enough of the magic it uses under the hood to even begin to answer that.  The whole point of this exercise was to start with the naive floating point implementation and see where I could make gains; I'm just shocked that the ARM, which is significantly more hardware, is an order of magnitude slower than the AVR.

Comment: @IanMcMahon, first thing I would do is look at the assembly.  Do you know what clock rate your ARM is using?  By default, it may start at a lower clock rate than the maximum (e.g. NXP LPC likes to start up at 12MHz).  I suggest you curl up with the datasheets and get to know them very, very well :-)

Comment: @IanMcMahon, also what is the size of double on your 8-bit and 32-bit processor?  Are they the same?  The sqrt, acos, and atan2 will probably use some sort of iterative scheme to calculate the numbers.  If they are calculating more bits, then it will be slower (you are probably wasting time calculating the final bits of the answer).  I'm not familiar with the AVR, so I don't know the specifics on this processor.

Comment: The ARM is 48MHz.  The thought about more work in the wider architecture is an interesting one :)

Comment: Check your IDE/environment/compiler/build whatever and be sure you get what you can get most of it. -  the question in this form is very poor.

Comment: @IanMcMahon, the ARM chip probably will support 48MHz.  However, have you confirmed it is actually running at 48MHz?  By default it will probably start up using its internal RC circuit and run slower.  You will have to dive into the registers and startup code to see if it is actually configured after startup to run at 48MHz.  Then you may be able to configure an I/O pin with a divider to output the SCLK (i.e. clock after PLL, which I'm guessing it has).  You'll need to post the exact part you are using for anyone to be able to supply more useful information.

Answer (score 4):

> ARM cortex M4

The FPU in the Cortex M4 only supports *single* precisition, but you use a lot of *double* in your code. This means software calculations instead of hardware. Have you tried to change the `double` variables - and function calls - to `float`?

Comment: Also, my understanding is that Arduino on AVR doesn't have `double`s - they're always `float`s.

Answer (score 0):

Curious problem! Try the following code as a quick way to check your clock speed:

```
boolean pinValue;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
   pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
   digitalWrite(13, HIGH);
   pinValue = true;
}

void loop() {
    pinValue = !pinValue;
    digitalWrite(13, pinValue);
}
```

Your logic analyzer should show an approximately 50% duty cycle of the Arduino going "as fast as it can". Use this to confirm your boards are being clocked as you think.

This will help you figure out whether your Teensy 3.0 is slow because of the time to perform a basic instruction, or whether the instructions for performing math functions are somehow less optimal for the ARM than for the AVR. If it is slower even for this simple program I would strongly suspect you are not clocking it the way you think.

I would recommend that you confirm that your probes are wired the way you think they are... i.e. is the "slow" channel really wired to the "fast" board?